# How to extract information from a dataframe name and create a column based on it

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's some mock data that represents the data I have:

```
pend4P_17k <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
pend5P_17k <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

I need to add a column to each data frame that represents the first letter/number code within the dataframe name, so for each dataframe I've been doing the following:

```
pend4P_17k$Pendant_ID<-"4P"
pend5P_17k$Pendant_ID<-"5P"
```

However, I have many dataframes to apply this to, so I'd like to create a function that can pull the information out of the dataframe name and apply it to a new column. I have attempted to use regular expressions and pattern matching to create a function, but with no luck (I'm very new to regular expressions).

Using R version 3.5.1, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Is the pattern always 'something followed by **1** digit, **1** uppercase letter, followed by something else'?

Comment: @markus The pattern sometimes contains 2 digits, 1 uppercase. For example, some of the dataframe names are "pend12P_17k," etc.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a pretty bad idea. It's better to keep your data frames in a list rather than strewn about the global environment. However, if you're insistent it is possible:

```
add_name_cols <- function()
{
  my_global <- ls(envir = globalenv())
  for(i in my_global)
  if(class(get(i)) == "data.frame" & grepl("pend", i))
  {
    df <- get(i)
    df$Pendant_ID <- gsub("^pend(.{2})_.*$", "\\1", i)
    assign(i, df, envir = globalenv())
  }
}

add_name_cols()

pend4P_17k
#>   x var1 var2 Pendant_ID
#> 1 1    a    1         4P
#> 2 2    b    1         4P
#> 3 3    c    0         4P
#> 4 4    d    0         4P
#> 5 5    e    1         4P

pend5P_17k
#>   x var1 var2 Pendant_ID
#> 1 1    a    1         5P
#> 2 2    b    1         5P
#> 3 3    c    0         5P
#> 4 4    d    0         5P
#> 5 5    e    1         5P
```

Comment: Is there a way you'd recommend doing it if they're in a list? I didn't have them in a list for this example, but I do eventually add them into a list later on to apply different functions to them.

Comment: My solution uses a list if you want ;)

Comment: @dobsonk2 you can use `lapply` to add the name to each column. The drawback is that you need a vector of the IDs that you want placed in each data frame. If the only place these names currently exist is in the name of global data frames, then you can get them by harvesting the names from the global environment as in my example.

Comment: @grouah your solution is quite creative, but it assumes a very specific structure for the names, will throw an error if there are any "missing" values between the numbered labels, and relies on `eval(parse`, which should not be used if it can be avoided.

Comment: @AllanCameron This function works great for dataframe names with a 1 digit, 1 number identifiers, but some of the dataframes have two digits, such as "pend10P_17k," in which the function no longer applies. I can't seem to figure out how to update the regular expression accordingly. I should have included an example such as this in my original post, so my apologies!

Comment: @dobsonk2 try changing the `gsub` to `gsub("^pend(.{2,3})_.*$", "\\1", i)`

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
require(dplyr)

f<-function(begin, end){
  ids<-seq(begin,end)
  listdf<-lapply(ids, function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0("pend", x,"P_17k"))))
  names(listdf)<-lapply(ids, function(x) paste0("pend", x,"P_17k"))
  len<-seq(1,length(listdf))
  
  for (i in len){
    listdf[[i]]<-listdf[[i]] %>% mutate(Pendant_ID=paste0(i+3,"P"))
  }
  
  list2env(listdf,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Gives the desired output:

```
> f(4,5)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

> pend4P_17k
  x var1 var2 Pendant_ID
1 1    a    1         4P
2 2    b    1         4P
3 3    c    0         4P
4 4    d    0         4P
5 5    e    1         4P

> pend5P_17k
  x var1 var2 Pendant_ID
1 1    a    1         5P
2 2    b    1         5P
3 3    c    0         5P
4 4    d    0         5P
5 5    e    1         5P
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *mget* and *rbindlist*:

```
library(data.table)

m1 <- mtcars[1:2, 1:3]
m2 <- mtcars[3:4, 1:3]

rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^m")), id = "myDF")
#    myDF  mpg cyl disp
# 1:   m1 21.0   6  160
# 2:   m1 21.0   6  160
# 3:   m2 22.8   4  108
# 4:   m2 21.4   6  258
```